# Visual Studio 2015 and Git: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlab

I'm using Gitlab and Visual Studio 2015 and when I push my changes to Gitlab projects, I receive the next error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Inner Exception:
    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

To setup my project, I followed the next steps:

1. Create a project in Gitlab.
2. Clone this project into my folder. In this step I needed to use the next command:

   `git config --global http.sslVerify false`
3. I created a project into this folder.
4. I have reviewed the repository settings and remotes is correct.
5. I did a commit to local repository.
6. I have tried to push this commit into remote and I have had the above-mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Visual Studio uses LibGit2 to handle the security checks and while it has one function to validate the connection, [it's never used and ifdeffed out](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get_check_cert).

If I remember correctly Visual Studio wraps the connection, but there is no setting to disable SSL security in the product.

Instead

- why not fix the certificate, a SSL certificate is not as expensive as it used to be
- why not add the certificate to the trusted certificate's list of your user by importing it in the Windows Certificate Store as a trusted Root Certificate?
- if your cert is valid, why not ensure that you're using the correct remote name

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add the certificate as Trusted Root Certificates but I did an error exporting certificate. Now, I have tried again and this works fine.