# Where does Visual Studio 2015 store its Git configuration information?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a particular installation of VS 2015 which is having problems connecting with a particular Git (not github!) server.  I would like to *clear the cache* as it were but cannot find information on where 2015 stores its git configuration information.

I have already tried removing the server name and adding it again.  That did not work.   I have *another* installation of VS 2015 on another machine which talks to this same git server successfully and I have other Git client software on the same box as the troublesome VS 2015 so I know the problem is not on the server side or the client box.

Comment: Are you talking about credential caching or about some other Git setting? Because Git settings are either in the global Git configuration or in the repo itself.

Comment: According to the tag, are you trying to connect with TFS GIT remote server, did you get any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 uses LibGit2 to talk to Git. And it stores its credential information in the Windows Credential Store. This sometimes causes Visual Studio 2015 to act differently than other Git clients.
[image: Windows Credential Store]

You can try clearing the stored credentials there

[image: Git credentials in the credential store.]

Other settings are stored in:

- System git configuration: `%ProgramData%\Git\config`
- Your global git configuration: `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`
- The Repository Git configuration: `.gitconfig` in your Repository root

On top of that credentials, port numbers and protocols can be stored in the remotes of your git repository.

If the repository requires a trusted certificate, [Visual Studio will reject the connection unless that certificate is installed in the Windows Certificate Store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572046/736079) and is trusted.

**NOTE This information is only applicable to Visual Studio 2013 - 2015.** Since Visual Studio 2017 the implementation of Git support has changed and now relies on the Git commandline client which is packaged in the Visual Studio installation. This introduces some interesting new issues, but also solves a couple of the compatibility issues you may be facing.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a git config file under your local git repo and your home directly such as `C:\Users\patrick` for global git configuration.

Without detail error info, it's hard to judge whether the issue is related to VS side or remote side. To narrow down the issue, suggest you to directly connect the git server by using git command line.

You could also double check  **[Git preferences and settings in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/git/git-config?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)**, make sure also settings are configured correctly.